# Kinds of GFCI receptable defects

Tags: electrical

Update 2: I think I have solved the cause of the gfci tripping whenever reset was pressed.

Yesterday. When I tried to teardown the GFCI to study the circuit and check the sense coil, I removed the MOV (metal oxide varistor) and melted the plastic housing of the sense coil. After I re-soldered the MOV, I put it nearer the coil. This may have resulted in flux irradiation of the coil resulting in constant tripping due to flux non-null induced current.

[image: 2]

It's working now after I removed the MOV and used wire to connect it to the terminal outside. If you have other theories why pressing reset could trip it before I removed the MOV. Let me know.

Update: i took it apart (tear down) and put back together and reset is working properly now. What parts in the circuit can become loose or shorted resulting in the reset always opening the relay? My guess is the sense coil which may have moved the position resulting in unbalance current? If you will force to simulate the condition where reset would open the relays. What must you do to the circuit? What parts must you open or short? This is to understand the circuit more and be familiar with its subtlety.

Original message:

What are the kinds of common GFCI defects?

In my case, with no connected load (none plugged in), whenever I press reset, there is a loud click as the relay opens immediately. So outlet can't be turned on. It's like there is an internal continuous imbalance in the sense coil even with no load attached. It is NOT an auto-monitoring self test model (which uses extra IC), but normal one with exact circuit diagram below. Has anyone encountered something similar to this? What GFCI defects have you encountered?

What part of the circuit could be damaged?

[image: 1]

http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf2/81/73/817329/rv4141a.pdf

Comment: What make/model is the GFCI in question?  Is it one of the newer ones with the "self-test" feature and/or LED indicators?

Comment: It has NO auto-monitoring self test, which uses an extra IC. My receptacle uses the exact circuit above. It has same defect as lock out. What caused the damage and what circuit in the above is damaged?

Comment: There is no connected load (none plug-in),  it just trips immediately when one presses reset. So it can't be turned on, how often is this defect in GFCI?

Comment: Why do you think a loud click is a problem if there is a down stream fault it will trip out. If it is a bad GFCI replace it, if it still trips you have a problem. The test button is a simple switch that connects the hot to ground through a high resistance resistor (in the mega ohms no no noise would be audible because it is less than 6 milliamps). Old ones are prone to failure but if down stream outlets are protected it will trip on those if wiring faults or downstream devices are faulty, I would replace it ,13$ is a cheap way to troubleshoot.

Comment: Shoot a photo of your test setup and edit it into the question.